# Download file through Angular and TypeScript

Tags: c#, api, angular, typescript

I'm having an issue in downloading a file in my Angular project. The problem is that when I try to navigate to the file's URL, the file does download successfully. But how can I implement the downloading function in Angular?

```csharp
[VRoute("PassportAttachments/{id}", 1)]
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public HttpResponseMessage GetPassportAttachmentById(int individualId, [FromUri] int id = -1)
{
    try
    {
        var attachment = _passportAttachmentManager.FindById(id);

        string attachmentPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
            string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IndividualPassportsPath"], individualId.ToString()) + attachment.FileName);

        //string downloadUrl = Url.Content(attachmentPath).Replace("/Api/Contacts/PassportAttachments/~", "");

        //var result = new { DownloadUrl = downloadUrl, AttachmentTitle = attachment.Title };
        //return Ok(result);
        if (File.Exists(attachmentPath))
            return new FileContentResult(attachmentPath, attachment.Title, FileResultType.ImageContentResult);
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Unit.Logger.Error(ex, ToString(), ActionContext.ActionArguments.ToList());
        return null;
        //return NotFound();
    }
}
```

`FileContentResult` constructor:

```csharp
public FileContentResult(string FilePath, string ResponeFileName, FileResultType fileResultType) : base(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    var stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    base.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    base.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachments") { FileName = ResponeFileName };

    switch (fileResultType)
    {
        case FileResultType.ZipContentResult:
            base.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
            break;
        case FileResultType.ExcelContentResult:
            base.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            break;
        case FileResultType.PDFContentResult:
            base.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            break;
        case FileResultType.ImageContentResult:
            base.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
            break;
    }
}
```

Now like I said, when I type the URL which downloads the file by myself (hence the `AllowAnonymous`) everything works fine. But function should I use or write to download the file using TypeScript

```typescript
public DownloadAttachments(): void {
    if (this.SelectedPassportAttachments != null && this.SelectedPassportAttachments.length > 0) {
        if (this.SelectedPassportAttachments.length == 1) {
            this.service.DownloadSinglePassportAttachment(this.SelectedPassportAttachments[0].Id, this.IndividualId).subscribe((file: any) => {
                // download file (function)
            });
        }
        else {
            this.service.DownloadMultiplePassportAttachment(this.IndividualId, this.SelectedPassportAttachments.map(pa => pa.Id), this.SelectedPassportNumber).subscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this when generating `.csv` files - `window.open("api/controller/get", '_self', '');`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a `Content-Disposition` header, the browser will automatically trigger a download dialog when it attempts to load the URL.

So you can either just navigate to the download location, or open the download location in a separate window (which will automatically close in most browsers when the download dialog appears):

```typescript
// navigate to the URL:
window.location.href = downloadUrl;

// or open a new window
window.open(downloadUrl);
```

Note that opening a window will be blocked by popup blockers if you run `window.open` outside from mouse events (for example button clicks). You can avoid that by opening the window *first* when the download button is clicked, and then change the URL later. Something like this:

```typescript
downloadAttachment() {
    const downloadWindow = window.open('about:blank');
    this.service.GetDownloadUrl(…).subscribe(downloadUrl => {
        downloadWindow.location.href = downloadUrl;
    });
}
```